# Highlighting embedded code snippets in vim

Tags: vim

I often edit markdown files with in-line code examples. these all start with the line “~~~ {.cpp}” (for C++). Is there an easy way to highlight everything between the line “~~~ {.cpp}” and the line “~~~” with C++ syntax hightlighting?

(Or even better, make it use “x highlighting” after “~~~ {.x}”.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip857) works for me. Maybe it is a starting point for further digging...